# Androidx - attribute android:requestLegacyExternalStorage not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=true` into my Manifest File and getting below error when i tried to build.

[image]

Actually i need this `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=true` because of [Dhaval2404/ImagePicker](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker) library recommendation.
Last 2 days i've tried couple of solution and still having same problem, When i remove it, everything working fine.

**Please help to solve this problem. **

**Here is my Gradle(app):**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.something"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.1.0' //scanner

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'//image loading library

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

    // room dependencies
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**Project Gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    ext.appcompat_version = '1.1.0'
    ext.androidxcore_version = '1.3.1'
    ext.utilcodex_version = '1.25.9'
    ext.gson_version = '2.8.6'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2' // weight scale plugin
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.something">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:name=".others.CriddamApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
        tools:targetApi="m">

        <activity
            android:name=".others.webview.SimpleWebView"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NOacTionbARWhite" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.criddam.medicine.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/images_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".notification.views.LockScreenActivityForAlarm"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and post the `AndroidManifest.xml` file that is causing the problems.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added Manifest, Please check now

Comment: That looks OK. Try raising your `compileSdkVersion` to 30 and removing the `buildToolsVersion`, and see if that helps. Plus, if you have not done so already, you might consider doing Build > Clean Project from the Android Studio main menu.

Comment: @CommonsWare bro, I did all the thing u said, but unfortunately having same problem :(